Initializing S3 client in Index file but want to access it in other files
Within the Index file of my server, I've defined
const s3 = new S3Client({ credentials: { accessKeyId: accessKey, secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey, }, region: bucketRegion, });
I want to use s3 to make a  request to the bucket but don't want to init a client in each file.
How would I be able to achieve module.export = { s3 } to access this client in other files.

Just use export on S3 like this
exports.s3 = new S3({
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
  Bucket: Bucket,
  region: region,
});

You can import this s3 object into other files and use it to interact with your AWS S3 bucket something like this:
const {s3} = require("../config/aws");

